# Play framework with SSL certificates from let's encrypt

Tags: java, playframework, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to work out how to use the certificates I got from let's encrypt with my standalone play application. I turned off my server and ran certbot which generated 4 files (cert.pem,chain.pem,fullchain.pem,privatekey.pem) but I don't know how to get my play application to use these.

I'm using version 2.5.4 of the play framework.

Comment: At least in play 2.4, this worked: Use the properties `-Dhttps.keyStore` and `-Dhttps.keyStorePassword` to specify the keystore that contains the private key. The play 2.5 docs suggest other properties: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfiguringHttps#SSL-Certificates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Play uses Java key stores to configure SSL certificates and keys.

So you have to do this:

1. Convert your Let's encrypt certificates to PKCS12
2. Convert PKCS12 to Keystore
3. Configure Play to use the keystore

---

**1. Cert and Key to a PKCS12 file**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key \
    -out server.p12 -name [some-alias] \
    -CAfile ca.crt -caname root
```

**2. Convert PKCS12 to Keystore**

```
keytool -importkeystore \
    -deststorepass [changeit] -destkeypass [changeit] -destkeystore server.keystore \
    -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass some-password \
    -alias [some-alias]
```

**3. Configure Play to use the keystore**

```
/path/to/your/app/app_name_script -Dhttps.port=443 -Dplay.server.https.keyStore.path=[keyStore-location] -Dplay.server.https.keyStore.password=[keyStore-password]
```